# How can I compare the stability of a variable with another variable over time?

Tags: time-series, validity

I have an instrument that measures two independent samples daily. If I know that the measurements of the first sample are accurate in a time period what is the best method to validate the measurements of the second sample in the same time period? i.e. is the instrument measurements stable over time? 
Can I use KS test?